# Enable log file rotation to s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have enabled this option.

[image]
Problem is:

```
If I don't press snapshot log button log, is not going to s3.
```

[image]

```
Is there any method through which log publish to s3 each day? 

Or how log file rotation option is working ?
```

Comment: take a look at `cron`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using default instance profile with Elastic Beanstalk, then AWS automatically creates permission to rotate the logs to S3.

If you are using custom instance profile, you have to grant Elastic Beanstalk permission to rotate logs to Amazon S3.

The logs are rotated every 15 minutes.

AWS Elastic Beanstalk: [Working with Logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.loggingS3.title.html)

Answer (score 3):

For a more robust mechanism to push your logs to S3 from any EC2 server instance, you can **pair LogRotate with S3**. I've put all the details in [this post](http://lustforge.com/2012/07/15/logrotate-apache-logs-to-amazon-s3/) as a reference whicould should be able to achieve exactly what you're describing.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Joseph, lol, I have found you approximately 20 times across Google now working on log issues.  You have a passion for logs! :)

Answer (score 3):

NOTICE: if you want to rotate custom log files, then, depending on your container, you need to add links to your custom log files in a proper places. For example, consider Ruby on Rails deployment, if you want to store custom information, eg. some monitoring using Oink gem in oink.log file, add proper link in /var/app/support/logs using `.ebextensions`

.ebextensions/XXXlog.config

```
files:
  "/var/app/support/logs/oink.log" :
    mode: "120400"
    content: "/var/app/current/log/oink.log"
```

This, after deploy, will create symlink:

```
/var/app/support/logs/oink.log -> /var/app/current/log/oink.log
```

I'm not sure why permissions 120400 are used, I took it from the example in Amazon AWS doc page http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html (seems like 120xxx is for symlinks in unix fs)

Answer (score -3):

This log file rotation is good for archival purpose, but difficult to search and consolidate when you need the most.

Consider using services like splunk or loggly.

Comment: It seems that OP was not looking for alternatives to log rotation, but rather just make it work.